# Android kotlin - check if null or empty returns non sense

Tags: android

This is the code:

```
if(prefs!!.getString("ttt", "") == "" || prefs!!.getString("ttt", null) == null){
    Log.d("letsSee", "ITS NULL: " + prefs!!.getString("ttt", ""))
}else{
    Log.d("letsSee", "AND ME?!: " + prefs!!.getString("ttt", ""))
}
```

The result is:

```
AND ME?!: null
```

What the.. ???!

How can I check if shared pref value is null or empty??

I also tried: `prefs?.getString("ttt", null) == null`

AND ALSO: `prefs?.getString("ttt", null).isNullOrBlank()`

**EDIT:**

The value of `prefs!!.getString("ttt", "")` was set from a API response which I made return null on purpose

Comment: Elwis operator would work `prefs?.getString("ttt") ?: "default_string"`

Comment: I don't think it would work with this specific case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying countless stuff I came up with this

```
prefs?.getString("ttt", null).toString() == "null"
```

Which is the only working solution!
smh..

Comment: Then, what if "ttt"'s value is actually the literal 4-character string "null"?

Comment: I wonder [SharedPreferences.contains(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String)) is a better solution?

Comment: Yeah maybe it's really just "null" string, didn't tested. But anyway it's android or it's library fault to convert empty/null to "null" and it's good to know for others which face this issue